# How do I find a max on separate sheets and indexing the name associated but ignoring a blank?

Tags: excel

I have several sheets that have a value of a crypto on each sheet and I am trying to find the max value and then print the name of the coin with that maximum value. But if one of the values of F5 is empty, how can I get the formula (below) to ignore an empty F5?

In the cells I am trying to print the name:

```
=INDEX(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&TEXTJOIN("</b><b>",,ADA:XRP!A5)&"</b></a>","//b"),MATCH(1,FREQUENCY(MAX(ADA:XRP!F5),ADA:XRP!F5),0))
```

There are several sheets in between ADA and XRP and A5 has the name of the coin associated.

In previous efforts, this has worked. But in this case now, the max comes up as the highest in the sheet to the left of the maximum if one of the sheets has a blank F5. I tried the same with LARGE (2) and the same issue.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

If the maximum value from `F5` in those sheets could never occur anywhere within the range `A5:E5` in any of those sheets:

`=LET(ζ,FILTERXML("<a><b>"&TEXTJOIN("</b><b>",0,ADA:XRP!A5:F5)&"</b></a>","//b"),INDEX(ζ,MATCH(MAX(ADA:XRP!F5),ζ,0)-COLUMNS(A5:F5)+1))`

Otherwise:

`=VLOOKUP(MAX(ADA:XRP!F5),IF({0,1},FILTERXML("<a><b>"&TEXTJOIN("</b><b>",0,ADA:XRP!A5)&"</b></a>","//b"),FILTERXML("<a><b>"&TEXTJOIN("</b><b>",0,ADA:XRP!F5)&"</b></a>","//b")),2,0)`

Or:

`=LET(ζ,COLUMNS(A5:F5),FILTERXML("<a><b>"&TEXTJOIN("</b><b>",0,ADA:XRP!A5:F5)&"</b></a>","//b[position() mod "&ζ&" = 1 and following::*["&ζ-1&"]="&MAX(ADA:XRP!F5)&"]"))`

Comment: This looks great - I tried the second one (the VLOOKUP) but I ended with an N/A error. 

I am not sure what you meant by "If the maximum value from F5 in those sheets could never occur anywhere within the range A5:E5 in any of those sheets:" 

Because the maximum in F5 could easily be smaller than others in A5:E5 so I am not sure that works.

Comment: Then you can't use the first option.